# People-Picker ignoring LDAP results for 2nd domain

Tags: people-picker

I've got a PeoplePicker that should be requesting users from two domains (with two-way trust), but is only showing users from the server domain.  The second domain has been set via the peoplepicker-searchadforests command, and the getProperty command brings up the correct information.

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn "peoplepicker-searchadforests" -pv "domain:two.com,two\admin,passTwo!" -url http://sp01/

stsadm -o getproperty -pn "peoplepicker-searchadforests" -url http://sp01/
--> returns <Property Exists="Yes" Value="domain:two.com,two\admin,****"  />
```

Also, peoplepicker-onlysearchwithinsitecollection is has a value of "no".

When searching in the pickerdialog, I've looked at the LDAP message request using MS Network Monitor, and the second domain controller is returning the correct list of users.  Those users are not shown in the people picker however, only the users from the server domain are being shown.

What do I have to do so that the people picker will show users from both domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the second domain was set up incorrectly.  Most likely it was set up as its own forest when it was created instead of being in the same forest as the first domain.  I created a new domain controller and putting it the same forest and created a few users and it all worked correctly.

So despite all the other steps being correct and having two-way trust between the domains, if they're not in the same forest, SharePoint still won't show the results or access any of the user information in the second domain (ie login etc).